# why do get a segmentation fault in this implementation of LinkedList

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a function `makelinkedList` which accepts the number of nodes in the linked List and returns the address of . The function `printlinkedList` prints the linked list.

I don't get a segmentation fault when I implement this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node linkedList;

void printlinkedList(linkedList** head){
    linkedList* crawler = *head;

    while(crawler!=NULL){
        printf("%d -> ", crawler->data);
        crawler= crawler->next;
    }
    printf("|NULL|\n");
}

linkedList* makelinkedList(int size){

    linkedList* crawler = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    crawler->data = --size;
    crawler->next = NULL;
    linkedList* head = crawler;
    while(size > 0){
        crawler->next = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
        crawler = crawler->next;
        crawler->data = --size;
        crawler->next = NULL;
    }
    printlinkedList(&head);
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    linkedList* node = (makelinkedList(5));
    linkedList** head = &node;
    printf("from main\n");
    printlinkedList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

OutPut of the code given above:

> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> |NULL|

But when I try to return the address of head (&head) I get a segmentation fault. The code that results in the fault is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node linkedList;

void printlinkedList(linkedList** head){
    linkedList* crawler = *head;

    while(crawler!=NULL){
        printf("%d -> ", crawler->data);
        crawler= crawler->next;
    }
    printf("|NULL|\n");
}

linkedList** makelinkedList(int size){

    linkedList* crawler = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    crawler->data = --size;
    crawler->next = NULL;
    linkedList* head = crawler;
    while(size > 0){
        crawler->next = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
        crawler = crawler->next;
        crawler->data = --size;
        crawler->next = NULL;
    }

    return &head;
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    linkedList** head = (makelinkedList(5));
    printf("from main\n");
    printlinkedList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I return the address of the head ?

Comment: Address of the local (and not static) pointer variable is not valid outside of the scope.

Comment: The first version of your code was just fine.. no need to mess with it. You could pass a single-depth pointer to `print` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head` is a local variable. Local variables are destroyed when the function that contains them returns.

So after `makelinkedList` returns, your "pointer to `head`" no longer points to `head`, since it doesn't exist. Typically, local variables get overwritten pretty quickly once they're destroyed, since *all* local variables share the same space in memory (the "stack"). By the time you try to use your pointer-to-`head`, that space no longer contains what `head` contained, but has been reused to store something else.

Answer (score 0):

As immibis explains in his answer, you cannot return the address of a local variable.  But the good new is you do not need to return the address, returning the value of `head` is all you need.  `head` is a pointer to the first element of the list, it carries all the information needed.

Indeed you can just pass `head` to `printLinkedList` as well after simplifying it to ljst take a pointer instead of a pointer to a pointer.

The real cause for confusion is the `typedef struct node linkedList`. The linkedList should really be just a pointer to the first node, but typedefing pointer types is even more confusing.  You can use a simpler typedef and use pointers to nodes in all your functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

void printlinkedList(node *head) {
    node *crawler = head;

    while (crawler != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", crawler->data);
        crawler = crawler->next;
    }
    printf("|NULL|\n");
}

node *makelinkedList(int size) {        
    node *crawler = malloc(sizeof(node));
    crawler->data = --size;
    crawler->next = NULL;
    mode *head = crawler;
    while (size > 0) {
        crawler->next = malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
        crawler = crawler->next;
        crawler->data = --size;
        crawler->next = NULL;
    }       
    return head;
}

int main(void) {
    node *head = makelinkedList(5);
    printf("from main\n");
    printlinkedList(head);
    return 0;
}
```